# GeoIP on shared hosting

Tags: php, spam-prevention, geoip

Some of the website's I've made are having problems with spammers. I've made sure that messages have to be approved before they are published, but lately it's been getting a lot worse.

There's only one link I can see between all the spam messages. All of the IP addresses are, according to `geoiplookup`, from China (and a few from Ukraine). I thought "Well, that's easy. Just block those 2 countries. It's a Dutch website anyway.". The problem is that the [GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) extension isn't installed on the shared hosting in question.

I'd prefer this solution over things like Captcha (nobody can read those bloody things anyway) or the need to register and login.
I'd also prefer not to depend on other websites, as they can go offline, or steal information.

Is there some other way to do it? The country is the only link I've been able to find. User agents same to be random, so do the IP addresses appart from all belonging to the same 2 countries. I've already implemented something that blocks users from posting over the Tor network, but they don't appear to be using Tor.

I know I can get somebody's location with Javascript, but that's client side and can easily be disabled.

Comment: just use an API to get the country. Theres lots out there.

Comment: @navnav And very little of them that work the way they're advertised.

Comment: What do you mean? Take a look at http://hostip.info or if you can be bothered to register an API key, http://ipinfodb.com. I've used both of them in the past and they work fine (return the basic **country** and **city**)

Comment: *"I'd also prefer not to depend on other websites, as they can go offline, or steal information."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Possible duplicate:
>   [How Can I Block Requests from China to My App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994773/how-can-i-block-requests-from-china-to-my-app)

Coincidentally OP on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994773/how-can-i-block-requests-from-china-to-my-app) had the same problem. Suggested was to do the following: (thanks to Lawrence Cherone)

You could try blocking the entire China IP range in the .htaccess

```
#China
deny from 203.135.96.0/19
deny from 203.208.32.0/19
deny from 202.165.176.0/20
deny from 59.108.0.0/14
deny from 210.25.0.0/16
deny from 202.95.252.0/22
deny from 219.216.0.0/13
deny from 202.170.128.0/19
deny from 60.247.0.0/16
deny from 221.13.0.0/16
deny from 125.96.0.0/15
deny from 202.38.0.0/20
deny from 203.192.0.0/19
deny from 202.122.128.0/24
deny from 218.56.0.0/13
deny from 203.166.160.0/19
deny from 202.122.112.0/21
deny from 203.190.96.0/20
deny from 219.72.0.0/16
deny from 124.172.0.0/15
deny from 210.79.64.0/18
deny from 198.17.7.0/24
deny from 202.168.160.0/19
deny from 203.91.120.0/21
deny from 220.160.0.0/11
deny from 202.127.192.0/20
deny from 202.127.216.0/21
deny from 60.253.128.0/17
deny from 58.82.0.0/15
deny from 202.85.208.0/20
deny from 124.249.0.0/16
deny from 202.90.224.0/20
deny from 59.192.0.0/10
deny from 192.83.122.0/24
deny from 202.38.152.0/22
deny from 202.69.16.0/20
deny from 210.14.128.0/17
deny from 124.240.0.0/17
deny from 222.240.0.0/13
deny from 221.176.0.0/13
deny from 203.191.16.0/20
deny from 124.200.0.0/13
deny from 202.60.112.0/20
deny from 203.94.0.0/19
deny from 221.12.0.0/17
deny from 221.14.0.0/15
deny from 202.152.176.0/20
deny from 121.4.0.0/15
deny from 210.82.0.0/15
deny from 203.152.64.0/19
deny from 121.76.0.0/15
deny from 59.191.0.0/17
deny from 221.196.0.0/15
deny from 202.165.208.0/20
deny from 125.254.128.0/18
deny from 210.14.64.0/19
deny from 203.212.80.0/20
deny from 202.112.0.0/13
deny from 58.87.64.0/18
deny from 61.45.128.0/18
deny from 122.51.0.0/16
deny from 210.32.0.0/12
deny from 202.93.252.0/22
deny from 202.90.0.0/22
deny from 125.216.0.0/13
deny from 222.64.0.0/11
deny from 60.194.0.0/15
deny from 210.23.32.0/19
deny from 124.196.0.0/16
deny from 203.158.16.0/21
deny from 192.124.154.0/24
deny from 122.0.128.0/17
deny from 203.208.16.0/22
deny from 202.127.16.0/20
deny from 202.38.184.0/21
deny from 210.192.96.0/19
deny from 210.56.192.0/19
deny from 202.173.224.0/19
deny from 222.125.0.0/16
deny from 202.20.120.0/24
deny from 58.32.0.0/11
deny from 202.164.0.0/20
deny from 210.5.0.0/19
deny from 202.8.128.0/19
deny from 202.150.16.0/20
deny from 203.86.64.0/19
deny from 202.63.248.0/22
deny from 203.174.96.0/19
deny from 220.252.0.0/16
deny from 210.185.192.0/18
deny from 203.156.192.0/18
deny from 203.110.160.0/19
deny from 203.95.0.0/21
deny from 222.16.0.0/12
deny from 59.172.0.0/15
deny from 202.38.136.0/23
deny from 121.224.0.0/12
deny from 203.191.64.0/18
deny from 221.129.0.0/16
deny from 121.40.0.0/14
deny from 210.21.0.0/16
deny from 59.151.0.0/17
deny from 202.170.216.0/21
deny from 203.130.32.0/19
deny from 121.100.128.0/17
deny from 202.127.12.0/22
deny from 124.254.0.0/18
deny from 203.135.160.0/20
deny from 124.250.0.0/15
deny from 202.14.88.0/24
deny from 202.181.112.0/20
deny from 202.38.160.0/23
deny from 219.242.0.0/15
deny from 203.191.144.0/20
deny from 220.242.0.0/15
deny from 61.29.128.0/17
deny from 221.133.224.0/19
deny from 203.196.0.0/21
deny from 202.0.176.0/22
deny from 122.0.64.0/18
deny from 220.154.0.0/15
deny from 222.168.0.0/13
deny from 220.248.0.0/14
deny from 218.185.192.0/19
deny from 124.160.0.0/13
deny from 202.38.168.0/21
deny from 121.56.0.0/15
deny from 121.55.0.0/18
deny from 202.91.128.0/22
deny from 121.59.0.0/16
deny from 123.49.128.0/17
deny from 220.232.64.0/18
deny from 203.100.32.0/20
deny from 202.122.32.0/21
deny from 202.38.138.0/24
deny from 202.14.235.0/24
deny from 203.171.224.0/20
deny from 202.4.252.0/22
deny from 124.224.0.0/12
deny from 202.38.128.0/21
deny from 121.51.0.0/16
deny from 202.127.112.0/20
deny from 166.111.0.0/16
deny from 124.108.40.0/21
deny from 203.207.128.0/17
deny from 218.104.0.0/14
deny from 58.30.0.0/15
deny from 124.156.0.0/16
deny from 202.14.236.0/23
deny from 125.31.192.0/18
deny from 203.90.128.0/18
deny from 124.66.0.0/17
deny from 202.136.208.0/20
deny from 210.16.128.0/18
deny from 221.0.0.0/13
deny from 203.128.32.0/19
deny from 61.128.0.0/10
deny from 58.116.0.0/14
deny from 202.130.0.0/19
deny from 192.83.169.0/24
deny from 202.94.0.0/19
deny from 202.46.32.0/19
deny from 60.232.0.0/15
deny from 61.87.192.0/18
deny from 203.222.42.64/26
deny from 60.255.0.0/16
deny from 124.20.0.0/15
deny from 121.32.0.0/13
deny from 202.38.140.0/22
deny from 203.184.80.0/20
deny from 58.144.0.0/16
deny from 210.15.0.0/17
deny from 124.68.0.0/14
deny from 219.128.0.0/11
deny from 121.204.0.0/14
deny from 202.127.128.0/19
deny from 218.64.0.0/11
deny from 124.108.8.0/21
deny from 125.213.0.0/17
deny from 202.74.8.0/21
deny from 61.236.0.0/15
deny from 61.48.0.0/13
deny from 219.224.0.0/12
deny from 121.0.16.0/20
deny from 125.98.0.0/16
deny from 222.192.0.0/11
deny from 202.180.128.0/19
deny from 121.89.0.0/16
deny from 202.96.0.0/12
deny from 203.100.80.0/20
deny from 203.88.192.0/19
deny from 121.248.0.0/14
deny from 221.200.0.0/13
deny from 202.38.158.0/23
deny from 202.38.149.0/24
deny from 162.105.0.0/16
deny from 210.15.128.0/18
deny from 221.172.0.0/14
deny from 125.215.0.0/18
deny from 218.192.0.0/12
deny from 202.131.48.0/20
deny from 202.92.252.0/22
deny from 220.192.0.0/12
deny from 202.38.146.0/23
deny from 203.95.96.0/19
deny from 202.69.4.0/22
deny from 58.128.0.0/13
deny from 203.118.192.0/19
deny from 203.128.96.0/19
deny from 202.136.224.0/20
deny from 222.126.128.0/17
deny from 122.200.64.0/18
deny from 61.8.160.0/20
deny from 202.38.150.0/23
deny from 58.192.0.0/11
deny from 203.212.0.0/20
deny from 124.248.0.0/17
deny from 222.128.0.0/12
deny from 203.92.0.0/22
deny from 202.38.192.0/18
deny from 221.199.224.0/19
deny from 210.79.224.0/19
deny from 202.91.0.0/22
deny from 221.224.0.0/12
deny from 203.208.0.0/20
deny from 203.207.64.0/18
deny from 202.149.160.0/19
deny from 202.149.224.0/19
deny from 202.189.80.0/20
deny from 203.80.144.0/20
deny from 58.66.0.0/15
deny from 202.70.0.0/19
deny from 210.78.0.0/16
deny from 203.209.224.0/19
deny from 202.131.16.0/21
deny from 58.24.0.0/15
deny from 202.179.240.0/20
deny from 202.4.128.0/19
deny from 202.14.238.0/24
deny from 222.176.0.0/12
deny from 222.160.0.0/14
deny from 220.112.0.0/14
deny from 167.139.0.0/16
deny from 122.4.0.0/14
deny from 202.153.48.0/20
deny from 221.12.128.0/18
deny from 211.144.0.0/12
deny from 211.64.0.0/13
deny from 124.6.64.0/18
deny from 125.112.0.0/12
deny from 203.83.56.0/21
deny from 124.29.0.0/17
deny from 124.16.0.0/15
deny from 202.136.48.0/20
deny from 61.47.128.0/18
deny from 124.40.128.0/18
deny from 202.127.212.0/22
deny from 203.148.0.0/18
deny from 59.64.0.0/12
deny from 122.48.0.0/16
deny from 124.42.0.0/17
deny from 218.249.0.0/16
deny from 124.242.0.0/16
deny from 203.132.32.0/19
deny from 203.79.0.0/20
deny from 202.38.176.0/23
deny from 202.43.144.0/20
deny from 202.123.96.0/20
deny from 203.175.192.0/18
deny from 125.171.0.0/16
deny from 211.136.0.0/13
deny from 203.128.128.0/19
deny from 192.188.170.0/24
deny from 122.8.0.0/13
deny from 124.67.0.0/16
deny from 202.91.176.0/20
deny from 124.243.192.0/18
deny from 221.122.0.0/15
deny from 203.90.0.0/22
deny from 210.28.0.0/14
deny from 202.122.64.0/19
deny from 220.231.0.0/18
deny from 210.52.0.0/15
deny from 220.234.0.0/16
deny from 202.38.164.0/22
deny from 202.127.224.0/19
deny from 203.81.16.0/20
deny from 202.127.48.0/20
deny from 134.196.0.0/16
deny from 218.0.0.0/11
deny from 60.63.0.0/16
deny from 203.93.0.0/16
deny from 124.72.0.0/13
deny from 61.240.0.0/14
deny from 202.127.40.0/21
deny from 202.127.208.0/23
deny from 125.210.0.0/16
deny from 211.96.0.0/13
deny from 61.28.0.0/17
deny from 60.235.0.0/16
deny from 202.158.160.0/19
deny from 121.46.0.0/15
deny from 59.80.0.0/14
deny from 203.176.168.0/21
deny from 121.60.0.0/14
deny from 202.143.16.0/20
deny from 58.154.0.0/15
deny from 221.208.0.0/12
deny from 210.51.0.0/16
deny from 218.108.0.0/15
deny from 61.232.0.0/14
deny from 121.201.0.0/16
deny from 124.88.0.0/13
deny from 221.198.0.0/16
deny from 203.161.192.0/19
deny from 203.119.32.0/22
deny from 202.38.156.0/24
deny from 202.92.0.0/22
deny from 221.130.0.0/15
deny from 168.160.0.0/16
deny from 222.32.0.0/11
deny from 203.86.0.0/18
deny from 121.16.0.0/12
deny from 203.92.160.0/19
deny from 202.46.224.0/20
deny from 121.8.0.0/13
deny from 59.107.0.0/16
deny from 203.91.96.0/20
deny from 122.198.0.0/16
deny from 221.8.0.0/14
deny from 219.82.0.0/16
deny from 202.93.0.0/22
deny from 60.55.0.0/16
deny from 125.64.0.0/11
deny from 203.187.160.0/19
deny from 58.14.0.0/15
deny from 124.64.0.0/15
deny from 202.38.64.0/18
deny from 125.58.128.0/17
deny from 203.119.24.0/21
deny from 203.100.192.0/20
deny from 202.165.96.0/20
deny from 202.160.176.0/20
deny from 221.192.0.0/14
deny from 202.120.0.0/15
deny from 203.100.96.0/19
deny from 202.127.160.0/21
deny from 202.75.208.0/20
deny from 125.62.0.0/18
deny from 124.220.0.0/14
deny from 202.91.224.0/19
deny from 202.10.64.0/20
deny from 202.90.252.0/22
deny from 202.127.0.0/21
deny from 220.231.128.0/17
deny from 60.208.0.0/12
deny from 218.96.0.0/14
deny from 203.222.192.0/20
deny from 60.200.0.0/13
deny from 210.87.128.0/18
deny from 125.208.0.0/18
deny from 210.22.0.0/16
deny from 125.32.0.0/12
deny from 121.58.0.0/17
deny from 202.136.252.0/22
deny from 221.199.0.0/17
deny from 203.99.16.0/20
deny from 203.175.128.0/19
deny from 203.91.32.0/19
deny from 210.76.0.0/15
deny from 60.245.128.0/17
deny from 121.192.0.0/14
deny from 203.89.0.0/22
deny from 220.152.128.0/17
deny from 210.72.0.0/14
deny from 58.16.0.0/13
deny from 202.0.110.0/24
deny from 121.68.0.0/14
deny from 202.41.152.0/21
deny from 202.131.208.0/20
deny from 221.199.192.0/20
deny from 203.223.0.0/20
deny from 124.112.0.0/13
deny from 202.125.176.0/20
deny from 203.90.192.0/19
deny from 123.99.128.0/17
deny from 221.199.128.0/18
deny from 60.0.0.0/11
deny from 202.142.16.0/20
deny from 161.207.0.0/16
deny from 202.130.224.0/19
deny from 159.226.0.0/16
deny from 210.5.128.0/19
deny from 58.100.0.0/15
deny from 124.47.0.0/18
deny from 221.136.0.0/15
deny from 218.240.0.0/13
deny from 203.134.240.0/21
deny from 58.240.0.0/12
deny from 202.141.160.0/19
deny from 210.12.0.0/15
deny from 203.88.32.0/19
deny from 202.148.96.0/19
deny from 202.95.0.0/19
deny from 222.248.0.0/15
deny from 211.160.0.0/13
deny from 203.99.80.0/20
deny from 60.160.0.0/11
deny from 202.41.240.0/20
deny from 122.49.0.0/18
deny from 211.80.0.0/12
deny from 123.199.128.0/17
deny from 202.192.0.0/12
deny from 202.22.248.0/21
deny from 219.244.0.0/14
deny from 202.122.0.0/21
deny from 59.32.0.0/11
deny from 125.104.0.0/13
deny from 124.192.0.0/15
deny from 124.147.128.0/17
deny from 124.128.0.0/13
deny from 202.173.8.0/21
deny from 210.26.0.0/15
deny from 121.48.0.0/15
deny from 220.101.192.0/18
```

Comment: What would that be like if I only want to bar them from the page `index.php?plugin=guestbook&function=new`?

Comment: @RobinJ Take a look [here](http://www.weethet.nl/dutch/html_usinghtaccess.php), probaply all you need to know about the .htaccess file (it's dutch, which I assume you speak ;) ). I'm pretty sure you don't need to specify it for any particular part of the site, just the file and it will block all access.

Comment: Is it possible that this isn't working correctly? I still get spam from China.

Comment: It should work if it's set up correctly. Is the ip who is spamming you in the ban list?

Comment: Nope, the IP doesn't seem to be in that list >.< How can I add an IP range to that list? Does `203.91.120.0/21` mean `203.91.120.0` to `203.91.120.21`?

Comment: @RobinJ no /21 is what's called the prefix (which tells you what the subnet is). In this case it means that the subnet is 255.255.248.0 which means there are 8192 subnets which can all host 2046 users (so that's 2046 users times 8192 subnets). That's the amount of users you will be blocking if you add that to the list.

Comment: Er... headache... so how do I add an IP range to the list?

Comment: @RobinJ If your tool says the ip who's spamming you is 203.91.120.0/21 just say "deny from 203.91.120.0/21", which then blocks all ip adresses coming from that range

Comment: I basically want to block every Chinese IP starting with `117.27.138`, as that's the most common IP range, although I don't want to block users from countries other than China.

Comment: @RobinJ Don't know, you could just try and say deny from 117.27.138.0 /8 I think? There are calculators out there that figure out what prefix you are supposed to use with that range.

Answer (score 1):

Maxmind - which is behind  the data the GeoIP extension is based on - has made an API implementation which works perfectly.

You can use it freely with their  free GeoIP product (GeoIP Lite).

http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the geoip extension. Just goto the geopip website and download one of the other options, like for example, make a mysql database or use the binary file option.